# Using a VPC from the office vs. VPN from home: Not all hosts are reachable

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, linux-networking, amazon-vpc

Here is my situation:

Our whole office is VPNed to an Amazon VPC through openvpn. 
We have 3 VPC subnets:

1. 10.1.25.x (Prod)
2. 10.0.3.x (Staging)
3. 10.0.1.x (build env)

While in this office, all is well and all resources resolve.

All of the OSx users can VPN from outside the office and reach all resources without issue.

When I VPN in from outside the office from Ubuntu 16.04, after [much hacking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285735/how-to-automatically-fetch-new-name-server-on-vpn-connect/286297#286297), I am only able to reach the build environment (#3).

Can someone explain what's amiss and where I might go look for ways to fix it? (Like, where on a working mac can I get information that I can replicate, etc.)

Debug:

```
root@christian:/var/log# traceroute -n internal-planseeker-prod-1929266821.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
traceroute to internal-planseeker-prod-1929266821.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com (10.1.22.185), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.27.232.1  26.526 ms  22.067 ms  22.224 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

It's all * * *

Comment: What are your IP(s) after you connected to the VPN? Could you post `traceroute -n` e.g. to prod?

Comment: @Putnik will update

Comment: Can you post the ouput of 'ip r' on the Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the same config on OSX and Ubuntu. Looks like after connection is established, you don't receive message that "hey, I (the gate you connected to) can route to 10.0.3.x and 10.1.25.x as well!"

Make sure your subnets are correct: 10.1.22.185 can be outside of 10.1.25.x

Re-check route table (locally)/router(s) in VPC, security groups/firewall at both ends.

Ensure you don't have `172.27.*.*` at VPC side except VPG point, or better check what IPs are at office/MAC when they're connected: if they are at `10.*.*.*` then perhaps you're connecting to wrong VPC(?)

Double check your subnets have proper mask and never overlapped.

Comment: A lot to track down, but I will have a peek